# JAVA - Adding Actions to Buttons

Tags: java, user-interface, button, jframe, actionlistener

First, this is an ongoing homework project in my quest to conquer JAVA (which I feel is going horribly!). It is also the first week in which GUIs were introduced and it has been and adventure. I was able to finally get the GUI to look like the example, thanks to the assistance of this awesome community. However, I have now gotten myself into a conundrum as I appear to have broke the GUI while adding actions.

I am getting numerous "illegal start of expression" alerts. I've cleaned the code as well as I can but somewhere, I'm missing something. With just the buttons and the panel locations the program compiles and looks like the following: [Correct ATM GUI look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iF3TJ.png)

I know I'm close to getting this to work correctly but at this point I need an experienced set of eyes to tell me where I need to go and what I'm doing incorrectly. I've posted the ATM.java code that is incorrect immediately below. I have also posted three other classes (I got them to compile!) which the buttons should call on to complete their actions.

ATM.java This is large, should I break this somewhere? I am using a previous program that I built and know worked as an example and it was all one file. I was thinking perhaps

```
//import statements
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ATM extends JFrame{

Account c,s;
public ATM(Account checking, Account savings){
    initComponents();
    c = checking;
    s = savings;
}

//create varialbes to add to JPanel
private JRadioButton radio1 = new JRadioButton("Checking");
private JRadioButton radio2 = new JRadioButton("Savings");
private JButton withdrawBtn = new JButton("Withdraw");
private JButton depositBtn = new JButton("Deposit");
private JButton transferBtn = new JButton("Transfer");
private JButton balanceBtn = new JButton("Balance");
private JTextField txtAmount = new JTextField();
//end variables declaration

public ATM(){
    super("ATM");
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    //add buttons to JPanel
    JPanel buttonsPanel1 = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    buttonsPanel1.add(withdrawBtn);
    buttonsPanel1.add(balanceBtn);

    JPanel buttonsPanel2 = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel2.add(transferBtn);
    buttonsPanel2.add(depositBtn);
    add(buttonsPanel2, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel buttonsPanel3 = new JPanel();
    buttonsPanel3.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    buttonsPanel3.add(radio1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    buttonsPanel3.add(radio2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    buttonsPanel3.add(txtAmount, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(buttonsPanel3, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

//creates action listener and assoicates it with Withdraw button
event withdraw = new event();
withdrawBtn.addActionListener(withdraw);
event deposit = new event();
depositBtn.addActionListener(deposit);
event transfer = new event();
transferBtn.addActionListener(transfer);

private class event implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent withdraw){
        try{
        String amm = txtAmount.getText();
        int withdrawMoney = Integer.parseInt(amm);
        if(withdrawMoney%20 != 0){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount must be in       increments of $20", "Error",0);
        }
        else{
            if(radio2.isSelected()){
                if(c.withdraw(withdrawMoney){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount Withdrawn Successful", "Message",1);
                }
            }
            else{
                if(s.withdraw(withdrawMoney)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Amount Withdrawn Successful", "Message",1);
                }
            }
        }
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry", "Error",0);
            }
        }
}

public class event implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent deposit){
        try{
        String amm = txtAmount.getText();
        int depositMoney = Integer.parseInt(amm);
        if(radio2.isSelected()){
            s.deposit(depositMoney);
        }else{
            c.deposit(depositMoney);
        }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Deposit Succesful", "Message",1);
        }catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry", "Error",0);
            }
        }
}

public class event implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent transfer){
        try{
            String amm = txtAmount.getText();
            if(radio2.isSelected()){
                if(s.transfer(transferMoney, c))
                    JOptionPane.showMexxageDialog(null, "Transfer Successful", "Message",1);
            }else{
                if(c.transfer(transferMoney, c))
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Transer Successful", "Message",1);
            }
        }catch(IllegalArguementException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Entry", "Error",0);
        }
    }
}

public class event implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent balance){
        if(radio2.isSelected()){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Balance is : "+s.balance()+"$","Balance",1);
        }else{
            JOptoinPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Balance is : "+c.balance()+"$","Balance",1);
        }
    }
}
//method will adjust size of the container to contain all controls
pack();
}
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Account a=new Account(12000,"Checking");
   Account b=new Account(10000,"Saving");

   ATM atm = new ATM(a,b);
   atm.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

InsufficientFunds.java

```
public class InsufficientFunds extends Exception{

String msg;

public InsufficientFunds() {
    msg="Insufficient Fund";
}

public String toString()
{
    return msg;
}
}
```

Account.java

```
public class Account {

int currentBalance;
String typeOfAccount;

public Account(int currentBalance, String typeOfAccount) {
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
    this.typeOfAccount = typeOfAccount;
}

public int getCurrentBalance() {
    return currentBalance;
}

public void setCurrentBalance(int currentBalance) {
    this.currentBalance = currentBalance;
}

public Account() {
}

public boolean withDraw(int ammount)
{
    try{
    if(currentBalance<ammount)
    {
        throw new InsufficientFunds();
    }
    else
    {
        currentBalance=currentBalance-ammount;
    }
    return true;
}catch(InsufficientFunds e)
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString(),"Error",0);

}
    return false;
}

public int balance()
{
    return currentBalance;
}

public void deposit(int ammount)
{
    currentBalance=currentBalance+ammount;
}

public boolean transfer(int ammount,Account sec)
{
  try
  {if(ammount>currentBalance)
    {
      throw new InsufficientFunds();  
    }
    sec.setCurrentBalance(sec.getCurrentBalance()+ammount);
    currentBalance=currentBalance-ammount;
    return true;
 }catch(InsufficientFunds e)
 {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e.toString(),"Error",0);
 }
  return false;
}
}
```

Comment: You can't have 3 different internal classes named "event".  Each class must have a unique name and should start with a capital letter.  I couldn't tell from looking at your code, but each o the 4 buttons and the checking / savings radio buttons should each have their own action listener.

Comment: Gilbert, thank you for the insight. I honestly had no idea as this is the first time I've attempted something like this. Were the project run from the command line I think I would be OK but this is making me want to toss my computer across the room.